# Cant disable borders .hta splashscreen

Tags: html, vbscript, hta

I tried to create a simple hta showing a simple splashscreen upon starting up.

Its supposed to show an image, have no borders, no scroll bar, no close button. I shows for 5 seconds and then auto closes. In the background it starts a process.

The only thing that doesnt work is it being borderless.

See pic: [The white borders are not supposed to be there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kI8p9.png)

This is the code:

```
<html>
<hta:application
    applicationname="splash load"
    id="splashload"
    version="1.0"
    border="none"
    innerborder="no"
    caption="no"
    sysmenu="no"
    maximizebutton="no"
    minimizebutton="no"
    icon="loader2.ico"
    scroll="no"
    scrollflat="yes"
    singleinstance="yes"
    showintaskbar="no"
    contextmenu="no"
    selection="no"
/>

<script language="VBScript">
    Sub CenterWindow(x,y)        
        window.resizeTo x, y      
        iLeft = window.screen.availWidth/2 - x/2      
        itop = window.screen.availHeight/2 - y/2    
        window.moveTo ileft, itop      
    End Sub    
    Sub Window_OnLoad
        CenterWindow 400,300
        iTimerID = window.setInterval("ShowSplash", 5000)
        Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
        objShell.Run """%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\LCDMisc64"""
    End Sub
    Sub ShowSplash
        Splash.Style.Display = "None"
        Window.Close()
    End Sub

</script>

<body>
    <div id="Splash">
        <p>
            <img src="8.gif"/>
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I rewrote the thing with help from here.

I think it works correctly now:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script Language="VBScript">
        Sub CenterWindow(x,y)        
            window.resizeTo x, y      
            iLeft = window.screen.availWidth/2 - x/2      
            itop = window.screen.availHeight/2 - y/2    
            window.moveTo ileft, itop      
        End Sub
        Sub window_onload
            CenterWindow 400,300
            window.setTimeout"Script", 5000, "VBScript"
        End Sub
        Sub Script
            Set obj=CreateObject("Wscript.shell")
            obj.run """%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\LCDMisc64"""
            Self.close
        End Sub
    </script>

    <hta:application
        applicationname="splash load"
        id="splashload"
        version="1.0"
        border="none"
        innerborder="no"
        caption="no"
        sysmenu="no"
        maximizebutton="no"
        minimizebutton="no"
        icon="loader2.ico"
        scroll="no"
        scrollflat="yes"
        singleinstance="yes"
        showintaskbar="no"
        contextmenu="no"
        selection="no"
    />

    <title>title is useless here :D</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    .bg {background-image:url(8.gif)}
    </style>
</head>
<body class="bg"></body>
</html>
```